# Google sheets IF, ISNUMBER, SUM formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a set of figures in Column A, and different figures in Column B. Here is some data:

```
Col A           Col B
1               1
2               1
3               4
4               27
5               19
5               -
-               7
-               -
```

I am showing the increase/decrease and am using this custom number format:
[Color10]▲ 0;[red]▼ -0;[blue]-

However, also have some of the following hurdles:

1. Some entries may contain "-" instead of a number. I want the hyphen to have a value that I define, such as "100".
2. When the hyphen exists, the formula `=(A1-B1)` outputs "#VALUE!" that I want to replace with other text.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with this, where I chose 250 as the figure for "-":

```
=sum(SUBSTITUTE(B2,"-","250")-SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-","250"))
```